# Sliced image repeates in storyboard but when I run the app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I use XCode's image slicing features in assets catalog to set slicing for an image. Then I use this image in storyboard: set it as image of `UIImageView`.

The size of `UIImageView` is larger than size of the image and thus the image is resized correctly as defined in its slicing. However, only in storyboard - once I run the app, the image is displayed in its original size at the top of `UIImageView`. It is not replicated as defined in slicing.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your UIImageView is resizing to fit the image, so make sure your Autolayout constraints are set up correctly. By default UIImageView tries to resize to fit its content, ie the image's nominal size. Add constraints for width, height, or left, right, top and bottom to make sure it isn't self-sizing.